# Alternatives to GetHashCode and applying in .Select

Tags: c#, linq, elasticsearch, hashcode

Hi all i have a large dataset which i am uploading to Elastic Search.

Elastic requires a unique id to upload an entry and i am using .GetHashCode() to achieve this in a lambda / linq statement.

```
var fullList = js.Select(x => "{\"create\": {\"_index\":\"" + elasticType + "\",\"_type\" :\"" + elasticType + "\", \"_id\" :\"" + x.GetHashCode() + "\"}}
```

The problem i am facing is the GetHashCode() produces the same value for some rows of data.

I have made sure each row's data is not the same by appending a row number to it, so each row is unique.  But the hash conflicts on occasion.

Is there 1) a better hash code function and 2) a way to incorporate that into the above code.  Or will i need to replace the lambda with a more verbose loop ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a row number then just use that.  Hash codes are not meant to be unique, they are just meant to be the same for equal values and hopefully spread out enough not to put too many items into the same bucket.

Comment: You could replace the hashcode with `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) a better hash code function

No, and it should be obvious. It's called [the birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), which states that with enough values that get put in a limited amount of buckets (ie hashed), you'll always have duplicates.

If you want an unique identifier, use an unique identifier. Hashing isn't that, and [neither are GUIDs](https://xkcd.com/865/). Use the row index if you have it, that's unique for your data set, and `Select` can return it to you while iterating.

Comment: ok i will find an alternative way.  This is a daily process so row number will not do it but i will combine certain pieces.  Thanks

Comment: @Jon date + row number.